# «Боль может быть разной(ая)?» - как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать:
«Боль может быть разной»
или
«Боль может быть разная»?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: боль может быть разной (Т.п.)

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Творительный падеж: нейтральный стиль, временный признак. Именительный падеж: разговорный стиль, постоянный признак. В нашем случае - временный признак.

ПРИМЕРЫ:
Огранка кристалла может быть разной. Их дальнейшая судьба может быть разной.